# How to remove or end Live activity from Lock Screen using push notification when app is in kill mode in iOS

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

"event: update" works perfectly fine.

**"event: end" not working nothing happens, only state data modified, live activity popup not removed from lock screen.**

{
"aps": {
"timestamp": 1168364460,
"event": "end",
"relevance-score": 75.0,
"stale-date": 1650998941,
"content-state": {
"driverName": "Anne Johnson",
"estimatedDeliveryTime": 1659416400
},
"alert": {
"title": "Delivery Update",
"body": "Your pizza order will arrive soon.",
"sound": "example.aiff"
}
}
}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/activitykit/updating-and-ending-your-live-activity-with-activitykit-push-notifications) there is a `dismissal-date` entry in the `aps` dictionary of your JSON payload. Setting this to a date (timestamp?) in the past will dismiss immediately.